# Howto create 100M Byte Buffer

Tags: linux-kernel

I am testing the throughput of an interface on Linux. I am using the DMA todo the data transfer. DMA needs contiguous memory location. But the kmalloc is unable to allocate more then 1MB. Is there any other way to create big buffer location upto 100M Bytes?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc

Answer (score 5):

I thought kmalloc couldn't allocate over 128kB, how did you get it to allocate 1MB ?

Anyway, assuming you're working on a freshly booted system, you can reserve up to 2048 contiguous pages. Pages are generally 4k, so this makes 8MB.

`_get_free_pages(_GFP_DMA, get_order(2048));`

However, if you need more memory, you should do the allocation at boot-time.
If you are writing a driver, this can be achieved with the `alloc_bootmem_*` functions.
If you are writing a module, you have to pass `mem=` argument to your kernel and later use `ioremap`.

For example, if you have 2GB, you can pass `mem=1GB` to forbid the kernel from using the upper 1GB, and later call `ioremap(0x40000000, 0x40000000)` to get access to the upper 1GB, just for you.

But you know, you should just split your huge buffer into many small ones, it'll be much easier and much more like real-life applications.

Comment: Thanks Heandel. I am writing driver. Already tried the scratch pad approach and left it in the middle with-out a success. Let me try again :)

Comment: Initially, I also thought, kmalloc cannot allocate more then 128KB. But in my testing, it is allocating 950KB. By the way, testing is on ARM. Will there be any arch specific diff?