# How to increase kmalloc() memory?

Tags: linux-kernel

In linux, dynamic memory can be allocated by kmalloc(). kmalloc() can allocate maximum 128k byte. How can i increase this allocation?
    Is kmalloc is slab allocation?

Regards
Learner

Comment: You'll probably need to change the source and compile the kernel. More details depend on distribution and version.

Comment: What do you need this memory for? Do you require it to be physically contiguous?

Comment: If memory is not required to be physically contiguous, you'd better use `vmalloc` which allocates memory region contiguous in virtual memory.

Comment: Refer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094673/kzalloc-maxmum-size-at-a-single-call

Comment: Is kmalloc slab allocator?