# What's the "right" way to use GFP_ZERO in latest kernels?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kmalloc

I found that on linux 3.0+ `GFP_ZERO` is no longer defined in headers.

All I found in gfp.h was,

```
/* Plain integer GFP bitmasks. Do not use this directly. */
...
#define ___GFP_ZERO     0x8000u
```

I've checked those "exported" bit masks, on one uses `GFP_ZERO`.

And the author says `Do not use this directly`, so, how should I get zeroed page,

Is `kmalloc + memset` the only option I have now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the expected way to zero is kzalloc():

https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kzalloc.html

but obviously alloc + memset works too.

**Update**

Sample diff from [CFQ](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/cfq-iosched.txt) showing the expected updates:

```
-   cfqd = kmalloc_node(sizeof(*cfqd), GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO, q->node);
+   cfqd = kzalloc_node(sizeof(*cfqd), GFP_KERNEL, q->node);
```

See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095263/2908724

Comment: Wow! Never know about this ;-P