# kmalloc'ed memory is slow

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

We have an app that requires ~1MB buffers for a hardware device to fill, therefore we wrote a kernel module that allocates buffers using kmalloc().  We did not use dma_alloc_coherent() as we need to manipulative the buffers and therefore wanted them to be cached (we flush the cache when needed).  One of the manipulations that is done is the kernel module copies one buffer to another buffer.  In timing these copies we see it takes about ~2ms to copy a buffer.  The time does not include any cache flushing.

As this seemed slow we wrote a standard userspace test app, that used malloc() to create 1MB buffers and copied them.  The userspace copies took about .5ms,  which is about the correct time to move this amount of memory on the processor/memory config we are using.

Thinks we tried: To make sure it wasn't a different memcpy() in kernel space and user space we wrote our own NEON optimized copy, but made no difference.  Changed the buffer size from 100KB to 10MB and made no difference.  All times were over 10 copies, but always very very consistent.  Time routine used gettimeofday() in userspace.

Only thing we can think of is that the data cache is setup up different for kmalloc()'ed memory then malloc()'ed memory???

We are working on iMX6 ARM, Linaro kerne.

Comment: How are you measuring the time taken?

Comment: Can you share your test code? Just to make sure there isn't something odd about it.

Comment: I'm curious - how is this not programming related? Why was it closed?

Comment: Not a clue, I was sure wondering that, do you know how to "unclose" it?

Comment: Folks who voted to close, please include a comment about how you'd like to see the question improved.  I'd vote to reopen if I had enough rep.

Comment: This is obviously ON topic.  There's a very disturbing trend here of closing difficult linux kernel programming questions.  If those unable to help in this area would simply stop reading this tag, we'd be in much better shape.

Comment: I did find if I use mlock() on the malloc()'ed memory, then the malloc()'ed memory is the exact same speed as kmalloc()'ed memory, so must be some cache flag somewhere doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The `kmalloc()` memory will be contiguous in physical space.  The user space will definitely not (`mlock()` may result in closer to contiguous).  If you have several SDRAM chips, it is possible that your memory controller allow  *pipelining* or *multiple issue* reads/writes to different chips simultaneously.  It may even be faster with multiple banks.  `vmalloc()` will not use contiguous pages.<sup>[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc)</sup>  You should be able to write a test to swap `kmalloc()` with `vmalloc()`.  If something has changed with the newer ARMs and the cache is not [VIVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), the difference in physical addresses could cause cache (aliasing?) effects on some processors.

I do not think that the cache are setup differently for kernel memory versus user memory; at least with 2.6.34 variants; but they may come from different pools.  Also, for a `memcpy()` a large cache is not needed; you just need enough to make sure the SDRAM will burst.

Another issue is peripherals.  For instance, a large graphics buffer on one chip maybe stealing cycles via DMA.  If you can change your *machine file* or *device table* to disable as many drivers as possible, this can be eliminated.   This combined with the *pipelining* could account for the type of slow-down observed.

I believe this is a *platform* issue.  If it was strictly Linux, I think that one of the millions of users may have encountered it.  However, you haven't given a specific version of Linux.  It could be an ARM based issue; so I tagged it as such.  I think it is your platform/ARM combination; simply because others would observe this.  Can you also provide a specific *machine file* or *device table* that your design was based upon and the Linux version.

Comment: The time for single beat versus a burst DRAM transactions would be about 10x.  There are several setup clocks for a single beat (one bit/byte/word depending on DRAM configuration) where as burst will share the setup over a whole line (burst is either 4 or 8; it could be bytes, 16 or 32 bits depending on DRAM size).