# When do we use vmalloc and kmalloc?

Tags: kmalloc, vmalloc

I know that kmalloc allocates contiguous memory in physical memory as well as virtual memory, vmalloc allocates contiguous memory in virtual memory but it doesn't guarantee that memory allocated in physical memory will be contiguous.

Therefore, it seems that kmalloc is much more better than vmalloc. I don't know when we use vmalloc, kmalloc? Can someone give me some examples using vmalloc in reality?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc?rq=1). I believe it also answers your questin. If not, can you edit your question to note that "I've read the other question and the answers did not go into ... ".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between vmalloc and kmalloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116343/what-is-the-difference-between-vmalloc-and-kmalloc)